# How to create an object in main() that every other class can access? (Java)

Tags: java, oop, scope

So I want to use the same object that I used in my main method to be able to accessed by all other classes.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The object must be declared outside `main` method as `static`. With this all the classes can access the same instance of the object, because it can only be one in the same JVM. Take a tour on the [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: If this answer sufficiently answered your question then you should accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `static` field in any class.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it `static` outside of the `main` method or you can pass it to the constructor of the other class.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a Singleton pattern which in the simplest (and thread-safe) form looks like

```
public class Single {
    private static final INSTANSE = new Single();
    //disallow instantiation outside
    private Single() {
    }
    public Single getInstance() {
         return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare it in the main method. You have to declare it as a static variable under the class.

IE:

```
public class Temp
{
    public static String a = "";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        a = "asdf";
    }
}
```

Now, you can access the variable a anywhere by calling Temp.a